# How to open a text box when I click on the button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have created a button which when clicked should open a text box or even a dialogue box. Once the user inputs the data it should save  and display the data there on the screen without reloading it.

Comment: Any code or html to share?

Comment: ok, whats the question, where is the code?

Comment: What does your html look like? are you using jquery-ui? what have you tried so far?

Comment: No source code = nothing to debug/work with. It's nice that you have created a button and your plans seem very interesting but useless to us without any source code to see/find the problem. *"I recommend only displaying the relevant source code to your question/problem"*

Comment: somebody give me right to downvote a question

Comment: Something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/j2qj7ph4/1/ ?

Comment: Hi Everyone , Thanks for your response. What I am looking for the suggestion of how should I go ahead and implement the same. That means I have not implemented the code as of now.

Answer (score 0):

Dont know about exact question but code something similar to you requirement.

```
<button type="button" id="btn1" >Button</button>
```

```
    $('#btn1').click(function(){
 $('#txtBox').show();
});
$("#txtBox").focusout(function(){
    $('#output').html($("#txtBox").val());
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6adxuf4c/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#btn1').click(function(){
 $('#txtBox').show();
});
$("#txtBox").focusout(function(){
$('#output').text($("#txtBox").val());
 $('#txtBox').hide();   //Use this line if you want to hide the textbox after showing the value 
});

<button type="button" id="btn1" >Button</button>
<input type="text" id="txtBox">
<div id="output"></div>
```

If you want to clear the textbox value every time then you can use the below code

```
$('#btn1').click(function(){
 $('#txtBox').show();
});
$("#txtBox").focusout(function(){
$('#output').text($("#txtBox").val());
 $('#txtBox').hide();   //Use this line if you want to hide the textbox after showing the value 
$('#txtBox').val("");
});
```